# Copy HTML Table to Text Box Using JQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, copy, plaintext

My problem has left me trying many solutions and stumped for a while now. My problem is exactly this:

There's a HTML table and a button on a page. Upon pressing the button, a script will run, copying the contents of the cells in the table into a text box. Here is the code for the table:

```
     <table>
        <tr><th></th><th>Category1</th></tr>
        <tr><td>1.</td><td class="rule">Rule1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2.</td><td class="rule">Rule2</td></tr>
        <tr><th></th><th>Category2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>3.</td><td class="rule">Rule3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4.</td><td class="rule">Rule4</td></tr>
        <tr><th></th><th>Category3</th></tr>
        <tr><td>5.</td><td class="rule">Rule5 </td></tr>
        <tr><td>6.</td><td class="rule">Rule6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7.</td><td class="rule">Rule7</td></tr>
        <tr><th></th><th>Category4</th></tr>
        <tr><td>8.</td><td class="rule">Rule8</td></tr>
    </table>
```

My first thoughts were to write a script that iterated through the table and copied the contents of each cell (and creating a new line after every 2 cells). I realized very quickly, that I had no idea how to do that. After some searching I was able to come up with a script that **clones** the table, and it actually works quite well. This code is here:

```
            $("button").click(function () {
            $("table").clone().appendTo(".copy");
            });
```

There are two problems that arise from using this method, however. I want plaintext, not a carbon copy of the table. The other problem is that this method only works when I clone the table into a div, it will not work when I try to clone it to a text box.

I've searched for a while for something similar to this and can only find solutions to copying single rows or cells. I had originally started there but couldn't figure out a way to write a loop that started at the beginning of the table and iterated through the entire thing, copying the contents as it iterated row by row (and creating a new line with each new row that it encountered). The loop would obviously end when there were no more rows to iterate through... This all sounds so simple to do, I know there must be a way.

Please Note: This script will be applied to a Site.Master Page so the script must be able to run for a plethora of tables. All of the tables follow the same structure shown above, but some will have more rows than others.

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to copy just the text between <td></td> or of all <th> and <td> tags?   $("td").each(function() {$(".copy").append($(this).text());}); ( example http://casewarecomputers.com:8088/soHelp.html )

Comment: I've looked at your example and modified it accordingly to insert a new line every two cells that the loop iterates. There's just two problems at this point: I also need the content in between the header tags (<th></th>) to be displayed. AND the table this script will be grabbing data from does NOT have a class or ID and going back through and changing over 200 tables to have a class or ID will be rough. Is there a way to make the script work on just any <table>? In most cases there will only be 1 per page.

Comment: I just added the id because until now, that page had a bunch of stuff on it.  The code works fine without a class or ID.  To get the header info however, do you just need the values from the headers and don't care the order?  Or are you aiming for Category1 1.Rule1...Category2 3.Rule3, etc?

Comment: Updated example: http://casewarecomputers.com:8088/soHelp.html

Comment: If you want all tables on a page in order. I can write another JS Snippet

Comment: The latter. I've modified the script you gave me here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PyN7K/). It runs but doesn't output any text and doesn't throw any errors in the Console using Chrome's debugger, so I'm not sure what I've done wrong, or if what I've done is even syntactically correct.

Comment: Haha wow, your solution is much more elegant and efficient. I have no idea what I was thinking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .each() JQuery Method:

**JS**

```
function cloneTableContents()
{
    $("table tr").each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).children().each(function() 
                                                {
                                                  $(".copy").append($(this).text());
                                                });
                    });
}
```

**JS For All Tables On Page In Order**

```
function cloneTableContents()
{
    $("table").each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).find("tr").each(function()
                                                {
                                                    $(this).children().each(function() 
                                                                            {
                                                                              $(".copy").append($(this).text()+" ");
                                                                            });
                                                });
                    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <table id="mine">
        <tr><th></th>
            <th>Category1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>1.</td><td class="rule">Rule1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2.</td><td class="rule">Rule2</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Category2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>3.</td><td class="rule">Rule3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4.</td><td class="rule">Rule4</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th><th>Category3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>5.</td><td class="rule">Rule5 </td></tr>
        <tr><td>6.</td><td class="rule">Rule6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7.</td><td class="rule">Rule7</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th><th>Category4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>8.</td><td class="rule">Rule8</td></tr>
    </table>
    <textarea class="copy"></textarea>
    <button onclick="cloneTableContents('mine','.copy');">Copy</button>
```

Working Example:
http://casewarecomputers.com:8088/soHelp.html

Comment: Thank you :), Please let me know if you need any more help with the code.